# Javascript broken randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the middle of development, and all of the sudden nothing related to javascript is working on my site.

http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/about/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Open javascript console and see the errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP didn't check their error console

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help. I had checked the error console previously and the 404s on the css was not connected. I got rid of those to make it easier to see. I am still getting errors for 'no method' that I can't seem to track down the source of the problem. Any more ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1):

you have these errors

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RadiantChurch.tv/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.0"
script...r=1.0.0
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RadiantChurch.tv/normalize.css?ver=1.0"
normal...ver=1.0
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RadiantChurch.tv/html5blank/style.css"
style.css
```

it would seem that your getting this because of a wrongly closed quote [`e.css?ver=1.0"` `js?ver=1.0.0"` `k/style.css"`] in one of you files (probably a `.php`)

it is also possible that the files (or folders) were simply renamed, or moved, make sure the files are where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Get a browser with debugging like chrome. Then show the debugger bar and check the console.

I see this, your missing css might be causing strange behaviour:

```
GET http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RadiantChurch.tv/normalize.css?ver=1.0 404 (Not Found) radiantchurch.info/:32
GET http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RadiantChurch.tv/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.0 404 (Not Found) radiantchurch.info/:39
GET http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/wp-content/themes/RadiantChurch.tv/html5blank/style.css 404 (Not Found) radiantchurch.info/wordpress/about/:142
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fitVids' RadiantChurch.js:56
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'
```